# Why does this result in a infinite loop?

Tags: java, loops

I am trying to program a method that will use Gauss Elimination on a matrix (2 dimensional array), and I'm trying to debug my method and I've encountered this problem

```
public int Gauss() {
    int i = 1;
    int j = 1;
    int pivotCol = 0;
    while (pivotCol == 0 && j <= cols())
        if (i == rows()){
            j ++;
            i = 1;
        }
        if (get(i,j) == 1.0){
            pivotCol = j;
        } else {
            i ++;
        }
    return pivotCol;
}
```

This is not the final method, but for some reason, this loop never ceases, why?

Comment: Are `rows()` and `cols()` nonzero integers? Are they fixed?

Comment: `get(i,j) == 1.0` you shouldn't compare floating point numbers with `==`

Comment: While the solution is brace-related, as the current answers point out, in the future if you've got a question about a while loop conditional, and that condition contains method calls as well as variables that will be effected by method calls within the body of that loop, you certainly should include the bodies of those method calls.

Answer (score 11):

```
while (pivotCol == 0 && j <= cols()) {
...
}
```

You forgot the brackets, so the while is only working with the if statement and therefore its running infinite.

Comment: Oooh - I was fooled by the indentation. Good eye.

Comment: No problem :) but you should accept Andrew Logvinov's answer for this question. He beated me and posted his answer 7 seconds before I did. ;)

Answer (score 7):

I guess the problem is that your while loop doesn't have curly braces, e.g. it's effectively as follows:

```
while (pivotCol == 0 && j <= cols()) {
  if (i == rows()){
    j++;
    i = 1;
  }
}
```

If `i != rows()` this will never terminate.